# how to use two level proxy setting in Python?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am working on web-crawler [using python].

Situation is, for example, I am behind server-1 and I use proxy setting to connect to the Outside world. So in Python, using proxy-handler I can fetch the urls.
Now thing is, I am building a crawler so I cannot use only one IP [otherwise I will be blocked]. To solve this, I have bunch of Proxies, I want to shuffle through.

My question is: This is two level proxy, one to connect to main server-1, I use proxy and then after to shuffle through proxies, I want to use proxy. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

**Update** Sounds like you're looking to connect to proxy A and from there initiate HTTP connections via proxies B, C, D which are outside of A. You might look into the [proxychains project](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/) which says it can "tunnel any protocol via a user-defined chain of TOR, SOCKS 4/5, and HTTP proxies".

Version 3.1 is available as a package in Ubuntu Lucid. If it doesn't work directly for you, the [proxychains source code](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/proxychains/proxychains-3.1.tar.gz?download) may provide some insight into how this capability could be implemented for your app.

**Orig answer**:
Check out the [urllib2.ProxyHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.ProxyHandler).  Here is an example of how you can use several different proxies to open urls:

```
import random
import urllib2

# put the urls for all of your proxies in a list
proxies = ['http://localhost:8080/']

# construct your list of url openers which each use a different proxy
openers = []
for proxy in proxies:
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': proxy}))
    openers.append(opener)

# select a url opener randomly, round-robin, or with some other scheme
opener = random.choice(openers)
req = urllib2.Request(url)
res = opener.open(req)
```

Comment: My question was not how to use set of proxies. Let me give you an example:There are 2 servers. I am behind Http proxy [external server]. I have to use some proxy ['http://proxy:port] to connect to the internet. After I am connected to external server, now I want to use set of proxies I have [ Random.choice ].  If I put in better words then this is kind of series [chaining] of proxies. Like, use http proxy to connect to external server and then after shuffle through set of proxies. server1--httpProxy--external server--shuffle proxies--So that IP remains random. Let me know if its vague.

Comment: Oops, sorry I misread that part of the question. I'll update my answer with some additional info.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will try to relate it to Python. Meanwhile, if you find anything around python [ Some python module ] then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take a look at CherryProxy.  It lets you send a proxy request to an intermediate server (where CherryProxy is running) and then forward your HTTP request to a proxy on a second level machine (e.g. squid proxy on another server) for processing.  Viola! A two-level proxy chain.

http://www.decalage.info/python/cherryproxy