# Is it possible to perform proxy chaining using python requests?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

Is it possible to perform proxy chaining using python `requests`? Or is there any external support that to achieve this, possibly by still using `requests`?

I mean something like:

```
r = requests.get(url=url, proxies={'http': [proxy_1, ..., proxy_n]})
```

so that the request is passes through each proxy.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with requests. But you should take a look here. http://www.hackershandbook.org/tutorials/proxychaining

Comment: You should look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5723259/710358 which links to http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways, I use the one below,

```
import collections, requests

def ChainProxy(a,proxies,url):
    r=a
    while True:
        try:
            r=r+1
            d = collections.deque(proxies)
            d.rotate(r)
            pp = list(d)
            pp = pp[0]
            stuff = requests.get(url, proxies={'http': 'http://'+pp}).content
            break
        except:
            pass
    return (r,stuff)
```

The way you use it is,

```
proxies = [a,b,c]
r=0

#And then repeat this everytime,
r,stuff=ChainProxy(r,proxies,url)
```

This gives you a new `r` every time as well as gives you the page source as `stuff`

I have implemented `try` and `except` because I always work with free proxies and many of them don't work :-) You may skip that step if you trust your proxies.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: This is not what I meant with 'proxy-chaining'. Here you are just trying a list of proxies and returning at the first success. What I'd like to achieve is to perform a request that pass through multiple proxies: A --> proxy1 --> ... proxyN --> B.

Comment: @se7entyse7en It won't just take the first proxy that work. But it will rotate the proxies everytime the fuction is called. I don't get what exactly you need. Could you be more specific?

Comment: please use descriptive variable names