# How to use python requests with proxies over Tor?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, proxy, tor

I have a python request with proxy:

```
proxy = {'https': 'http://ip:port'}
res = requests.get("https://api.ipify.org", proxies=proxy).text
```

And also I have a request over Tor:

```
tor = {'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9051'}
res = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org', proxies=tor).text
```

How could I throw a request over tor from proxy ?

```
(A->PROXY_SERVER->TOR_NODES->B)
```

Comment: `tor` runs as local proxy server. You can't connect from internet to your local server - you would have to redirect/forward port. But I don't know if you can use two proxies - it may need to send special request to first proxy with address to second proxy and with final address in arguments - but I don't know if it possible

Comment: [proxy - Python: HTTP request using two proxies at the same time in a defined order - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69379897/python-http-request-using-two-proxies-at-the-same-time-in-a-defined-order?rq=1)